# Spring Boot application Rest endpoint[If we hit] is giving me the Connection pool shut down issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cloud

Spring Boot application is deployed in AWS Cloud.When ever if we hit that application it is giving me the below exception/error response, May i know why.?

But the application is opening through swagger successfully.
http://:/swagger-ui.html is opened successfully.!

```
{
  "timestamp": 1576227944695,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Connection pool shut down",
  "path": "/api/v1/XXXX/VVVVVV/21321321"
}
```

Configuration [application.yml & bootstrap.yml]

```
spring:
  application:
    name: XX-XX-XXX
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        health-check-path: /health

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
      exposure:
        include: '*'

spring:
  application:
    name: xx-xxx-xxx
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://cfg.service.consul
      fail-fast: true
```

Exception Details:

```
    Dec 16, 2019 9:52:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:267)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:176)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.postForMap(RemoteTokenServices.java:147)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication(RemoteTokenServices.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: But, if we hit that above rest endpoint from local it is giving me the correct response.

Comment: So you expect us to know what is wrong without seeing code, configuration etc.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to give you the details, basically we are fetching the database and another token related information from the cloud configuration.

in Data-dog logs i observed that when if we hot the rest endpoint it is trying to calling the cloud config URL after that nothing is happening.

Cloud Consul
https://www.consul.io/docs/


spring:
  application:
    name: xxxxxx
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://cfg.service.consul
      fail-fast: true

Comment: spring:
  application:
    name: xxxxxxxxxxxx
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        health-check-path: /health

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
      exposure:
        include: '*'

Comment: Don't add additional code, config etc. as comments. Edit the question instead to add it.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the additional code and config.Thank you.!